# Problems with Outlook/Office365/SharePoint/OneDrive and Ubuntu + Chrome browser

Tags: google-chrome, office365

Is anyone aware of problems with Ubuntu 18.04 + Chrome and Outlook/Office365/SharePoint/OneDrive (for business)? Both Ubuntu and Chrome are up to date.

I have intermittent problem where the pages won't load or buttons/links on the page don't respond.

When the pages don't load, they'll either sit with the browser loading symbol twirling, or I'll get an error message saying "This site can't be reached", or "Something went wrong".

When buttons/links don't work, there's just no response whatsoever.

The problems will generally last for a 5-30 minutes and then be fine again.

Our IT team are adamant there's nothing wrong their/Microsoft side and that it's a problem with my OS/browser, but I don't have problems on any other websites, just our internal MS for business pages.

Comment: sounds like an authentification issue. are you using any adblockers?

Comment: No I'm not using adblockers.

Comment: If your IT team isn't supportive, it maybe more practical to use the OS/browser they recommend.

Comment: So Chrome is the recommended browser, and while it'd make their life easier if we all switched to Windows, 1) the Windows users have their own problems and 2) the way we're funded means IT have to be open to OS's of all flavors. Plus a Windows machine just to check my email and share documents doesn't fix the problem and is somewhat excessive :-)

Comment: Same problem with 20.04 also. Office365 does not work with any browser on ubuntu, Chrome or Firefox.